# Targeting only hovered element in a list of elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is to have only selected, in this case hovered, element replaced by video. Right now all elements that share same class get replaced when one of them gets hovered.

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/darkodemic/pen/QdJPMO).

I have read about using $(this) but I cannot figure out how to implement it here.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thank you.

Code here as well:

html:

```
<div class="main-parent">
  <div class="img-container">
  <div class="video_overlays">
    <a href="http://dev.mintv.rs/sta-je-i-kako-se-pravi-zanatsko-pivo" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://dev.mintv.rs/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/1a-1.jpg" alt="Thumb" class="thumb_image" />
      <video class="thumbnail_player" src="http://dev.mintv.rs/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Kabinet.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop></video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <span class="duration">03:13</span>
</div>
<div class="desc"><p>Title</p></div>
</div>

<div class="main-parent">
  <div class="img-container">
  <div class="video_overlays">
    <a href="http://dev.mintv.rs/sta-je-i-kako-se-pravi-zanatsko-pivo" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://dev.mintv.rs/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/1a-1.jpg" alt="Thumb" class="thumb_image" />
      <video class="thumbnail_player" src="http://dev.mintv.rs/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Kabinet.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop></video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <span class="duration">03:13</span>
</div>
<div class="desc"><p>Title</p></div>
</div>

<div class="main-parent">
  <div class="img-container">
  <div class="video_overlays">
    <a href="http://dev.mintv.rs/sta-je-i-kako-se-pravi-zanatsko-pivo" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://dev.mintv.rs/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/1a-1.jpg" alt="Thumb" class="thumb_image" />
      <video class="thumbnail_player" src="http://dev.mintv.rs/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Kabinet.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop></video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <span class="duration">03:13</span>
</div>
<div class="desc"><p>Title</p></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main-parent {
  width: 360px;
}

.img-container {
  height: 202px;
  width: 360px;
  position: relative;
}

.video_overlays {
  position: absolute;
  width: 360px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0);
  z-index: 300000;
}

.video_overlays video {
  display: none;
}

.duration {
  z-index: 300001;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  line-height: 24px;
}

.desc {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

js:

```
jQuery('.img-container a').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').css("display", "block");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("autoplay", "true");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("loop", "true");
    jQuery('.thumb_image').css("display", "none");
  },

  mouseleave: function() {
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').css("display", "none");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("autoplay", "false");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("loop", "false");
    jQuery('.thumb_image').css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

Comment: Add `, this` after all selectors -> `jQuery('.thumbnail_player', this)` ([jQuery, selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context))

Comment: Or use jQuery(this).find('.thumbnail_player');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('.img-container a').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    var $element = $(this).find('.thumbnail_player');
    var $image = $(this).find('.thumb_image');
    $element
      .css("display", "block")
      .attr("autoplay", "true")
      .attr("loop", "true");
    $image.css("display", "none");
  },

  mouseleave: function() {
    var $element = $(this).find('.thumbnail_player');
    var $image = $(this).find('.thumb_image');
    $element
      .css("display", "none")
      .attr("autoplay", "false")
      .attr("loop", "false");
    $image.css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery('.img-container a').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').css("display", "block");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("autoplay", "true");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("loop", "true");
    jQuery('.thumb_image',this).css("display", "none");
  },

  mouseleave: function() {
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').css("display", "none");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("autoplay", "false");
    jQuery('.thumbnail_player').attr("loop", "false");
    jQuery('.thumb_image').css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

Comment: This was solution. Thank you.
        jQuery('.img-container a').on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                jQuery('.thumbnail_player', this).css("display", "block");
                jQuery('.thumbnail_player', this).attr("autoplay", "true");
                jQuery('.thumbnail_player', this).attr("loop", "true");
                jQuery('.thumb_image', this).css("display", "none");
            },
    
            mouseleave: function() {
                ...
            }
        });

Comment: @DarkoDemic Why do you mark a wrong answer as the "accepted answer"? The only valid answer right now is the one from [thesublimeobject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42178031/402037)

Comment: Did not see that one, was posted after I have selected answer. Both work. @thesublimeobject was complete so I am selecting that one as right answer as you recommended.